# SP10 : SharePoint in IE take undefined array, but not when out of SP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, javascript, html

I got a bug with my SharePoint that when my Javascript runs, it's going to read in an array the news and make it appear in P in a marquee. The only thing is that in SP10, it's appear that he takes another row that doesn't exist and make it undefined. 
For the Javascript :

```
        var announcement = [
        "Bienvenue à tous !",]

    var span = "";

    for (var intCpt = 1; intCpt <= announcement.length; intCpt++) {
            span = span + '<img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/Megaphone2.png">' + " " + announcement[intCpt-1] + " " +  '<img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/Megaphone1.png">' + '</br>';
    };
    document.getElementById("banderole").innerHTML = span;
```

Here's the HTML :

```
<marquee class="deroulant" direction="left" behavior="alternate" scrollamount="8">
        <span id="banderole"></span>
</marquee>
```

Here are the [Images for the bug](https://imgur.com/a/WThJU)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like my code wasn't as good as I though.

```
        var announcement = [
    "Bienvenue à tous !",]

var span = "";

for (var intCpt = 1; intCpt < announcement.length; intCpt++) {
        span = span + '<img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/Megaphone2.png">' + " " + announcement[intCpt-1] + " " +  '<img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/Megaphone1.png">' + '</br>';
};
document.getElementById("banderole").innerHTML = span;
```

Answer (score 0):

So when I add this code, it seems it doesn't work on Chrome. The problem here is Internet Explorer way to read comma in the new array. The fixed I found is here !

```
        var announcement = [
        "Bienvenue à tous !",
        "Aucune nouvelle disponible",
    ]
    Array.prototype.tidyTrailingElisions = function() {
        var i = this.length;
        while ( !this.hasOwnProperty(--i)) {}
        this.length = ++i;
        return this;
    };

    var span = "";

    for (var intCpt = 1; intCpt <= announcement.tidyTrailingElisions().length; intCpt++) {
        span = span + '<img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/Megaphone2.png">' + " " + announcement[intCpt-1] + " " +  '<img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/Megaphone1.png">' + '</br>';
    };
    document.getElementById("banderole").innerHTML = span;
```